# Difference between iPhone and iPad applicationDidEnterBackground

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, background

I have an iPhone app and an iPad app which have an identical code base (other than the xib files being different for each platform).  In the app delegate of each app, I have NOT overridden the applicationDidEnterBackground method.

When I run the iPad application, then press the home button, if I touch the application icon the app comes up right where it left off (same screen, etc).

When I run the iPhone application, then press the home button, if I touch the application icon the app will start up as if it were not running.

Both show to be running if you double-click the home button before touching the application icon again.  The only difference is in the behavior of the iPhone app.

I would like the iPhone app to behave like the iPad app (continue running and not restart), but I cannot seem to find any difference that would prevent it from working like the iPad version.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: applicationDidEnterBackground is not an override but a `UIApplicationDelegate` protocol implementation. Implement it (and others delegate methods) with  some log and check if it is called, that might help to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You probably also have different Info.plist files for the two apps. Check whether the iPhone version has [UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/CoreApplication/CoreApplication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH3-SW24) set to YES.

Answer (score 0):

The iPhone 3G always restarts apps, newer devices can restore apps from background.